# Does Android send Wi-Fi probe requests to saved hidden networks?

Tags: wi-fi, wpa-supplicant

Let's put this scenario:
I manually add an existing Wi-Fi network that does not broadcast SSID. For some reason the encryption passphrase doesn't match, so authentication is impossible. Previously hidden SSID is now shown in Wi-Fi networks list.

Click on hidden SSID that is now shown and forget its settings. Click on the same hidden SSID now presented on the list and set a correct passphrase. Authentication is done successfully.

My question is if the network is still considered a hidden network on `wpa_supplicant.conf`?

In the future if Android client does not send a direct probe request for a specific hidden SSID and instead sends a broadcast probe, will it be unable to detect the network?

Answer (score 3):

A hidden or non-broadcast WiFi Access Point remains always hidden i.e. it always sets SSID to `null` in [beacon frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame) it sends. However once you manually add its SSID to a [supplicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_supplicant), it depends on the latter whether it explicitly scans the former in future or not. Android's WiFi client is `wpa_supplicant`, the same is most commonly used on other Linux-based OSes. From `wpa_supplicnat` configuration [manpage](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/wpa_supplicant.conf.5.html):

> ***scan_ssid***
>   SSID scan technique; 0 (default) or 1.  Technique 0 scans for the SSID using a broadcast Probe Request frame while 1 uses a directed Probe Request frame.  Access points that cloak themselves by not broadcasting their SSID require technique 1

So `scan_ssid=1` is usually the default behavior on most OSes. Also Windows built-in supplicant can *["connect even if the network is not broadcasting"](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28653)*.

> In the future if Android client does not send a direct probe request for a specific hidden SSID and instead sends a broadcast probe, will it be unable to detect the network?

Yes definitely. But scanning hidden networks is default setting up to Android 8. In Android 9 a new configuration was [added](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/8bc3fa0649a3ecff5e42fb0d14ddb8ff6f7f7507) to allow explicitly setting the behavior:

[image]

> My question is if the network is still considered a hidden network on `wpa_supplicant.conf`

In Android whole configuration is not added to [`wpa_supplicant.conf`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/wpa_supplicant/hidl/1.1/supplicant.cpp#34) file but retained by Android framework. Since Android 8 it's [stored](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/cbfc6a05c171b8a441abad28afdef54f54f9c2cd) in `WifiConfigStore.xml` files located under `/data/misc*` directories. According to user selection, `scan_ssid=[0|1]` - along with other configurations - is [passed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/wpa_supplicant/hidl/1.1/sta_network.cpp#741) to `wpa_supplicant` process over HIDL - an Android specific IPC - or possibly over global `ctrl_interface`.

To summarize, yes Android (by default or optionally) sends direct probe requests to saved non-broadcast WiFi networks.